# Construct a sampler for the product of two distributions, given samplers for each distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have two distributions $P_1$ and $P_2$, and I have black boxes for sampling from them $X_1 \sim P_1, X_2 \sim P_2$. I can easily construct a way to sample from the mixture of $P_1$ and $P_2$, by flipping a coin, then using the result to determine whether to draw from $P_1$ or $P_2$. Is there an analogous way to sample from the product of the two distributions $X \sim P$ where $P = P_1 \times P_2$, or, if this is easier, from $P = (P_1 \times P_2)^{1/2}$?

If not, how would one construct a formal argument showing that this is not possible?

Comment: The product distribution means that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, therefore you can just generate $X_1\sim P_1$ and $X_2\sim P_2$ with no dependence between the two and you are done.

Comment: @P.Quinton - I am not asking about the distribution of the product of X_1 and X_2; the distributions are being multiplied and not the samples. Just as with a mixture distribution, which is not the same as the distribution of the sum of samples from each mixture component.

Comment: The product distribution is the distribution of $(X_1, X_2)$ when they are independent right ?

Comment: @P.Quinton - No, I'm also not asking about the distribution over pairs $(X_1, X_2) \sim (P_1, P_2)$. Assuming that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are distributions over the reals, the product distribution is a distribution over the reals, with (unnormalized) probability $P(x) \propto P_1(x) P_2(x)$.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is not typically named the product distribution, but the product of distributions.

Comment: For discrete distributions, you can generate parallel sequences from your black box generators until $X_1=X_2$ and then output the shared value as a single sample.